# How do I prototype an online game?

Tags: networking, prototyping

I would like to know if you guys know of any libraries, engines, or even simply design patterns that heavily simplify the task of sharing information and sending of messages between networked programs, so one can focus on tweaking gameplay instead of rewriting networking code, while prototyping networked games. Since this is meant for prototypes, ease of use and flexibility is much more important than speed and security.

Comment: Well, I've heard that Unity is capable of creating MMO style games, however it is an Engine that focuses on 3D, you can do 2D but you just have to get a bit creative (like make a plane that contains the 2D sprite as a texture and set the camera to look down.) I know 3D buzz made a tutorial on Unity MMO programming, but I don't think it is available to the public. I suggest you being with Paper Prototyping, which is where you try to create a game using paper cut outs and move things on your own, it is a good way to get feedback without creating the full game, just handle online events yourself.

Comment: [ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) is awesome for reducing networking boilerplate.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson I've used Unity, but their networking components are too specific for sharing object positions. You have to write your own engine on top of it if you want to use it for something else, and that defeats the entire purpose of prototyping.

Comment: @Anko 0MQ seems interesting, and I'll give it a try. I'm worried it that it tries to simplify the _transport_ layer, which most likely means that eventually, you're going to have to write your own application protocol, which is precisely what I want to avoid for the prototyping phase.

Comment: Based on the rewrite, 0MQ (or RabbitMQ) will work fine.  No messaging system can automate your game's data replication, the contents of the message will always be up to you to create and interpret.  Heck, on a LAN you could simply spam broadcasts and anyone listening could pick out packets meant for them, data could be XML or JSON or an easy key-value text pair stream because for prototyping locally you're guaranteed to have tons of bandwidth.  But you still have to do code work.

Comment: @PatrickHughes Are you sure no messaging system can automate the data replication? That's what remoting, WCF, and many other protocols are supposed to do. Simplifying the boilerplate code is irrelevant, because you have to do it once, while message creation/interpretation has to change as every rule changes. I'm picturing something like annotating or registering variables so they are automatically synchronized between clients, with the addition of RPC.

Comment: Is this a "what technology to use" question?

Comment: @TrevorPowell hopefully more like a "what design pattern to use" question.

Comment: Even systems that kind of automate marshalling and unmarshalling data packets via serialization require a DDL (data definition language) or modifications to your source and so you're still doing the maintenance and it's almost as easy to manually change the serialization code yourself as compared to learning yet another custom description language and system.  What language are you using?  Language choice may help others answer your question more specifically.

Comment: @PatrickHughes I'm quite flexible regarding languages. Even though I'd prefer if it were in C/C++/C#/Java/Python/Lua, I don't mind using something else, especially since this is for throwaway prototypes. It would be really cool if there were a language, or a language extension that lets you transparently share variables across computers. (Wait, does something like that exist?)

Comment: For ideas on that: Look at Raknet and what they call object replication at their front page, find Google's "protocol buffers" which you might like to roll your own (though it's a DDL), or run a search on "Object Replication" which is the magic word you might have been looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to prototype an online game, which allows you to quickly change almost anything in the game (even factors such as real-time vs. turn-based), is to implement the prototype as a physical game.  Get all the designers together in a room, get a bunch of cards, or dice, or board game components, or whatever is necessary to prototype the general game interactions.  Then play the game.

You can do this without needing to pay programmers or artists.  Trying different variations of game rules takes only a minute or two instead of requiring hours or days (or weeks!) of programming work, and you can know whether or not your game works by actually playing it, instead of having to design ahead of the implementation and make guesses about what will or won't work.  Plus, your programmers will still like you at the end of the process.  :)

- When doing this, I recommend having at least one person acting as an
  observer; not taking part in the game itself, and another person
  whose job is to keep notes about who did what and when.  That data
  about what actually happened during each game can become tremendously
  useful while adjusting the rule set between games.

Pen, paper, dice, cards, boards, tokens.  That's really all you need.  And for prototyping a game design, it's better than anything else.

Comment: Yeah, I've done this, but it is almost impossible in a professional environment where everybody has stuff to do, and asking for undivided attention from several people for 30 minutes at the same time is almost impossible. Giving a binary to some coworkers and playing it while talking on skype is much more feasible.

Comment: On the contrary.  If your workmates refuse to do what's demonstrably the fastest and most economical way for the company to rapidly iterate on a prototype game design, then you are **not** in a professional environment.

Comment: Let's not turn this into a workplace discussion. Certainly physical prototyping is very good, but it's not always possible, and not all games are trivially physically playable. I can usually hack single player 2D game ideas in a few hours, and modify them to see if they're interesting. I just want to be able to do the same for multiplayer games.

Comment: You're the one who brought up work environments, not me.  If you don't want to talk about them, that's fine.  But don't expect me to stay silent while you make claims that physical prototyping somehow can't work in "professional" work environments.  Because that's simply not true.

Comment: My claim is that it is difficult in a "professional environment where everybody has stuff to do, and asking for undivided attention from several people for 30 minutes at the same time is almost impossible". Maybe yours is a "professional environment where you can ask people to test your game whenever you feel like it". There are many types of professional environments, and discussing whether or not the place I work is professional enough, does not get me closer to an answer.

Comment: Also, not all games are trivially physically prototypable. Puzzle and strategy games are easy to do with your proposal, but action, musical, racing, sports and simulation games may not be so.

Comment: No method will magically make prototyping 'trivial' for any type of game (much less for *every* type of game). Doubly so when networks are involved. That it's 'not trivial' is not a reason to dismiss any method of prototyping, because you're never going to find a method that *is* trivial.

Comment: This is one element that was in my original question before I edited it, which provided some context. I am a _programmer_, not a _game designer_. I have experience designing networking architectures for games. This means that: 1. I prefer programming solutions to my problems, 2. I'm not looking for point-and-click solutions, I can and have prototyped directly with sockets, I just want to know if I can do it easier. And 3. My job is not game designing, but programming, therefore it is unreasonable for me to ask people for their time for things that are not in my primary job description.

Answer (score 2):

`relatively simple rule changes such as "let's try this in real time instead of turn-based"` That sounds like a pretty fundamental change to me, not a simple rule change. I think fundamental design choices like that should be made before you even get to writing any networking code, either with offline prototypes or even paper prototypes.

That is, prototype the gameplay without doing any networking. That would mean writing a game that is multiplayer locally (ie. both players are on the same computer) in order to test gameplay ideas.

I mean, at my job we once took a game that was already halfway developed turn-based and converted it to real-time, and yeah that involved a massive rewrite of the networking code. In retrospect, that was a really inefficient way to approach things, and we pretty much decided "never again."

Comment: Not really, if it's not networked, changing a turn based game into real time is not very difficult. The problem with trying on the same computer is that you're limited to two, or maybe up to four users at the same time. Anyways, that was one example, but there are many other things I want to test that can definitely be made easier to test if they are actually networked...

Comment: Not understanding the point of your first sentence. That's exactly what I'm getting at, that making that gameplay change is easy if the game isn't networked. And if there are other things that can only be tested once networking is actually in place (eg. syncing over the internet) then make as many decisions as possible *before* you start worrying about that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a need for such a tool because I believe network logic is best done through a solid analysis of what information needs to go where.

But, if I were forced to create such a thing for someone who wanted one, I would use:

- the Python programming language
- 0MQ for messaging (via [pyzmq](http://zeromq.github.com/pyzmq/))
- the pickle module to send arbitrary data (as given [in an example here](http://zeromq.github.com/pyzmq/serialization.html))

This covers all the problems of reliable transport, message delineation, and serialisation/deserialisation. (Pickle is not safe for anything other than intranet use however.)

You will still need to set up the logic to decide what to do with the data, make and implement the decision of which computers connect to which other computers, and so on. And it doesn't support unreliable messaging, or remote procedure calls, or automatic state replication, etc etc. That's why it's usually better just to plan out what you want and write it that way.